# How to troubleshoot high CPU usage on GCP Serverless VPC connector?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have setup a serverless VPC connector to route all ingress and egress traffic from a Cloud Run service instance. The instance counts are set to default min of 2 and max of 10. Currently there are 8 instances running. The cloud run service is not receiving any requests and therefore the VPC connector should be "idle". However, I see spikes in CPU usage > 80% and it doesnt seem to come down at all. Docs say instances of VPC connectors scale out but not in. And since these are "serverless" I cannot SSH into them. How do I troubleshoot the root cause of the spikes?

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough reputation to post a comment I'll post it as an answer.

If your VPC connector is not hitting the limit [Throughput](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access#scaling) and Cloud Run is not experiencing any timeouts and disconnects, then there is nothing to worry about the high CPU Utilization at this point.

If you wish to troubleshoot the root cause of the spike, these are the steps I recommend you can try.

- Go to CPU Utilization of the VPC connector and take note of the date and time where the CPU Utilization spike is greater than 80%.
  Go to the `Metric section` of your Cloud Run and check if there is an increase in the `Request count`, `Sent bytes`, `Received bytes` and `Max. concurrent requests` the same time the CPU Utilization spike in the VPC connector.
- If you notice an increase in the Metric section of your Cloud Run, that could simply explain the high CPU Utilization on the VPC connector. If you notice no increase, you can troubleshoot further by [Enabling VPC Flow Logs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-flow-logs#enable-logging-existing) and use [Logs Explorer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface) to retrieve, view, and analyze log data. Make sure to set the resource to `Subnetwork` > `SUBNETWORK_ID` > `SUBNETWORK_NAME` of the VPC connector when you run the query.